# Unable to run jsp in jboss 7.0 with eclipse neon

Tags: jsp

MY code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hi
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:446)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:607)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.1.Final logs.

Comment: I am using java 8 , Please give me a solution Thanks in advance

Comment: You talk about Java SE. In this case it is Java EE. You need Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. Please provide more information.

Comment: I am using eclipse neon IDE and i have created a dynamic web project.
I can run html file in that project(jboss 7.0) only i have problem with JSP.

Comment: It works fine in apache tomcat server, and i have problem with jboss as 7.0 server.

Comment: found the issue - jboss as 7 doesn't support java 8 . I have downloaded wildfly10 its working fine.

Comment: Eclipse Neon itself must be run using Java 8 not your JSP. But its ok. You have found working solution.

Comment: @VelanK Thanks a lot. I got the same error since yesterday and I have gone crazy because it was working well in tomcat, but not in JBoss 7.1. Once again thanks, man.